# How do I convert nchar to string in C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, tostring

Forgive me if this question has already been asked and answered. I just spent some time searching for my question, and I can't seem to find it.

Anyway, I'm working in Visual Studio 2010 and MS SQL Server. I've got the database made and I'm just working on the front end stuff now. Anyway, through my searching, I have seen that nchar is not a C# data type, which is fine, but it won't seem to convert it to a string for me.

```
Convert.ToString(reader["SerialNum"].ToString().Trim());
```

That's the part that is giving me an error. It's saying "Cannot implicitly convert 'string' to 'int'."

Anyone know a way to get around the whole nchar issue?

Thanks in advance!

Ellie

[EDIT]:
So here's the whole method... though I don't think anything else in here will really help.

```
private Row PopulateRow(SqlDataReader pReader)
    {
        Row CurrentRow = new Row();
        CurrentRow.sTransNum = Convert.ToInt32(reader["STransNum"].ToString().Trim());
        CurrentRow.serialNum = Convert.ToString(reader["SerialNum"].ToString().Trim());
        CurrentRow.itemTypeID = Convert.ToInt32(reader["ItemTypeID"].ToString().Trim());
        CurrentRow.fromLocation = Convert.ToInt32(reader["FromLocation"].ToString().Trim());
        CurrentRow.toLocation = Convert.ToInt32(reader["toLocation"].ToString().Trim());
        CurrentRow.units = Convert.ToInt32(reader["Units"].ToString().Trim());
        CurrentRow.serialMoveDate = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["SerialMoveDate"].ToString().Trim());
        CurrentRow.moveTypeID = Convert.ToInt32(reader["MoveTypeID"].ToString().Trim());
        CurrentKey.sTransNum = CurrentRow.sTransNum;
        CurrentRow.CompleteState = "OK";
        return CurrentRow;
    }
```

Comment: have you try using string s = Convert.ToString(reader["SerialNum"]); ?

Comment: The sample code doesn't appear to be the source of the error.  There's no `int` in that line at all.  Is that the entire line?  Could you post a larger sample, for context?

Comment: This seems like a database message.  is your query trying to cast astring as an int?

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs it seems to me like a compiler error.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs I assume she's converting some string to an integer in some code that she hasn't posted.  I believe it is a compiler error because the text exactly matches the compiler error you get when you try `int x = "Some text";`.

Comment: @HerNameIsEllie, check the property definition of `CurrentRow.serialNum`, make sure it's not defined as `int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to assign the value you received to an int.  Check the definition of the variable/ property you are assigning the value to.

Answer (score 3):

Probably should use [reader.GetString(ordinal)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getstring.aspx)

```
reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("SerialNum"))
```

If the value can be null in the result, use reader.IsDbNull(ordinal)

```
int ordinal = reader.GetOrdinal("SerialNum");
serial = reader.IsDbNull(ordinal) ? null : reader.GetString(ordinal);
```

Comment: The error has nothing to do with this answer.  Why is this upvoted?

Answer (score 0):

```
Convert.ToString(reader["SerialNum"])
```

but you are probably assigning to an int variable. More code please.

Comment: I tried that, still didn't work... And I added more code up at the top, though I doubt it really helps.

Comment: I am pretty sure CurrentRow.serialNum  is of type int. Also use properties and not public fields and if serialNum is in fact property use proper convention. (This has nothing to do with your problem but is good practice)

Answer (score 0):

The are a few things wrong here.

1. You are casting twice. There is no need.
2. C# is not a [weakly typed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_typing) language so you must put the result of your conversion into another string.

So try either of the following

```
string strTmp = Convert.ToString(reader["SerialNum"]);
strTmp = strTmp.Trim();
```

or

```
string strTmp = reader["SerialNum"].ToString().Trim();
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah, I'm upset about the casting twice thing, too, but that's how my boss does it, and since I'm the new one here, I just gotta step along sometimes... but I'm saying I've done this a thousand times before with all the other tables.. It only has a problem with this ONE because it's an nchar. That's something worth noting. I'm not saying how I'm doing this whole thing is the right way to do it, but it has worked up until now.

Comment: @HerNameIsEllie, look at agent-j's answer above.  SqlDataReader understands nchar and knows how to cast it.

Answer (score 0):

Is that the full line of code giving you an error?  The error indicates you are trying to convert to an int.

Answer (score 0):

> The full line is CurrentRow.serialNum = Convert.ToString(reader....);

I bet `CurrentRow.serialNum` is an integer.

If that's correct, depending on the type of the data in the reader, one of these will be your solution:

```
CurrentRow.serialNum = Convert.ToInt32(reader["SerialNum"].ToString().Trim()); 
CurrentRow.serialNum = (int)reader["SerialNum"];
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not be a data type issue, but rather a NULL issue.  Verify whether serialNum can be NULL.  If so, you may need to use GetSqlString or other code that can handle the NULL case.